# Get Values form text Fields in UITableView Custom Cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I have Created a custom `UITableViewCell`, the cell has multiple text fields, now i want to access the strings or data in these `UITextFields`. I know i can get the cell on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, but i need to get the text on a "Save" method.

Comment: i'm facing same problem in my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/lowbgnqzk05ej8d/Alert.zip

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Suppose you have four text fields with tags 100 and so on to 104.
You will you Counter that shows how many cells you have in tableview.

```
for (int i=0; iLessThanCounter; i++) {
            
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: i inSection: 0];
                
     UITableViewCell *cell = [mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                
     for (UIView *view in  cell.contentView.subviews){                
                    
           if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]){
                        
                  UITextField* txtField = (UITextField *)view;
                        
                  if (txtField.tag == 100) {
                         NSLog(@"TextField.tag:%u and Data %@", txtField.tag, txtField.text);
                  }
                  if (txtField.tag == 101) {
                        NSLog(@"TextField.tag:%u and Data %@", txtField.tag, txtField.text);
                  }
                  if (txtField.tag == 102) {
                        NSLog(@"TextField.tag:%u and Data %@", txtField.tag, txtField.text);
                  }
                  if (txtField.tag == 103) {
                       NSLog(@"TextField.tag:%u and Data %@", txtField.tag, txtField.text);
                  }
                  if (txtField.tag == 104) {
                       NSLog(@"TextField.tag:%u and Data %@", txtField.tag, txtField.text);

                  } // End of isKindofClass 
              } // End of Cell Sub View
         }// Counter Loop
    }
```

Comment: This way will solve the purpose. But best way is to do it through delegates.

Comment: If you do have large number of views inside the cell this code will be ambiguous. You are conterminously checking tag on `if conditions`, even you are not using `else if` or the best tool for this scenario `switch statement`. And if you directly get the view for a specific tag then why do you iterate with a loop?

Comment: @manileo86 help me i have faced same problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/lowbgnqzk05ej8d/Alert.zip

Comment: help me i have same logic

Comment: perfect only for the visible cells in the tableview...but one cannot get data for the cells scrolled up.

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use `viewWithTag` to get your desired views. Suppose you have one imageview with tag 100 and one text view with tag 200.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [mytableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *getImageView = (UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
UITextField *getTextView = (UITextField*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:200];
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create instance for each textField in your header file. Look at this sample demo

http://windrealm.org/tutorials/uitableview_uitextfield_form.php

You can access textfield's text property for getting the text value for a particular textfield

Comment: I have multiple textFields in a cell, & there are also multiple cells,

Comment: so you can keep references for all of them

Comment: one more solution is above solution from Muhammad Junaid Sidhu which might do the work